# Run a foreign exe inside a Python GUI (PyQt)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to run an exe (for example calc.exe or cmd.exe) inside a python gui (python 2.7 | Windows | PyQt).
Have anybody an idea how can i do this? 
(something like that : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6GWgxEvibE)

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Does this have to work in PyQt4, or could you use PyQt5? I think you may need the latter to get this to work on Windows. (I assume you're asking about embedding external windows in your own application).

Comment: How can i make it with PyQt5? I want to include the cmd.exe there. In linux i had done this with xterm and fit it into a qwidget successfully. But in windows this doesnt work :(. Thx in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by run an exe inside a python gui?

Comment: @SDE What does embedding another app's window in your app provide, over just starting the other app as a separate process?

Comment: @Schollii Yes. It should work like the youtube link, which i have post above. I have now change to pyqt5.

Comment: @SDE would you have a full solution example to this question for me? I am aiming to achieve the same thing however I can't find the complete solution

Answer (score 10):

```
import subprocess
import time
import win32gui

...

def initUI(self):
    # create a process
    exePath = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe"
    subprocess.Popen(exePath)
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, "CalcFrame", "计算器")
    time.sleep(0.05)
    window = QWindow.fromWinId(hwnd)
    self.createWindowContainer(window, self)
    self.setGeometry(500, 500, 450, 400)
    self.setWindowTitle('File dialog')
    self.show()

...
```

- 01 create a process, run your exe
- 02 use spy++ to get hwnd of the exe
- 03 create QWindow from hwnd
- 04 create window container

Result:

lose exe'menu

[image]

Comment: Can this be extended to work on Linux, any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide the full code that runs this example? Thank sir.