# How to use PyQt method QWindow.fromWinId(id) on linux?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, hwnd

I'm trying to embed a foreign executable inside of a Python GUI (PyQt) just like this post describes: [Run a foreign exe inside a Python GUI (PyQt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474647/run-a-foreign-exe-inside-a-python-gui-pyqt)
but the answer requires the win32gui module, which doesn't seem to be available on linux systems. The PyQt method (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html):

--> QWindow.fromWinId(id)

does what I need, but I'm not sure how to get the handle id (hwnd) of the window of my executable (for the record, I'm trying to embed saods9 within my GUI) on linux (Ubuntu). Everything I'm finding looks to be geared toward a Windows operating system, not Linux. So I'm thinking that this Qt method can't be used on a Linux operating system?

That would be my question: How do you get the handle id of a native window within Linux to be used in the Qt method QWindow.fromWinId(id)?

Comment: Use one of the many external tools like `xwininfo` or `wmctrl`.

Comment: Thank you ekhumoro! I was able to download and use xwininfo.