# pyqt5 createWindowContainer not contain other exe inside application

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to open one exe application in PYQT5 window

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474647/run-a-foreign-exe-inside-a-python-gui-pyqt) and this [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816766/how-to-embed-a-pptk-viewer-in-a-pyqt5-window)

I tried the following:

```py
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
    import numpy as np
    import win32gui
    import sys
    import pygetwindow as gw
    
    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    
            widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget)
            self.setCentralWidget(widget)
    
            self.cloudpoint = np.random.rand(100, 3)
            exePath = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\calc.exe"
            subprocess.Popen(exePath)
            time.sleep(2)
            hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, None, "Calculator")
            # wins = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Calculator')
            #
            # xbox_win = None
            # for win in wins:
            #     if win.title == 'Calculator':
            #         xbox_win = win
            #         xbox_win.maximize()
            #         wiwi = win
            # hwnd = wiwi._hWnd
            # win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)
            self.window = QtGui.QWindow.fromWinId(hwnd)
            self.windowcontainer = self.createWindowContainer(self.window, widget)
    
            layout.addWidget(self.windowcontainer, 0, 0)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        app.setStyle("fusion")
        form = MainWindow()
        form.setWindowTitle('PPTK Embed')
        form.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 500)
        form.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but the result is as shown below:

[image]

As can be observed the GUI's are bound together in sizing. When changing the PYQT window, the calculator size also changes.

**Question**

> So why does the calculator go out of the PYQT5 window frame?

> How do I show the calculator inside the PYQT5 frame?

> I have no prejudice to using PYQT5, any GUI in Windows accepted

I am using **PYQT 5.15.9**

Comment: Window embedding has always been known to be problematic with external applications, as it has important issues with proper "widget" management and keyboard/focus interaction. As far as I know, it's provided only for situations in which the "guest" program is aware (or provides support) for embedding, otherwise its behavior is just undefined and unreliable.

Comment: thank you for answer , do you know other solution for this work? i want embedding external application in python application looklike iframe in browser

Comment: I only know about Qt, and while the documentation doesn't make any explicit mention, embedding external top level windows of other (arbitrary) applications is not officially supported. It *may* be possible with a toolkit specific to the given OS, but in this era of very different window management implementations, you never know if will always work, and it may not even work completely for some types of programs, depending on how they manage their internal rendering (ovelay, direct GPU/display access, etc).

Comment: @hn_tired Which *specific* external application are you trying to embed? If you're not actually interested in embedding Calculator, there's no point wasting time on it, since you can easily create your own calculator in PyQt that will be far superior. Embedding should only ever be considered as a last resort. Always look for alternative solutions that provide the same functionality *first* - or even consider writing your own implementation. In almost all cases, this will provide **much** better results (no matter what toolkit you use).

Comment: thanks for answer. i want to embed xbox remote play on windows. but maybe i want embed some other applications.