# Can I embed a processing window in a PyQt5 app?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, processing

The question is quite simple: Is it possible to embed a processing (https://py.processing.org/) in a PyQt5 app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy built in way to do it, but Qt does support embedding external applications. I suggest you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474647/run-a-foreign-exe-inside-a-python-gui-pyqt) and the reference [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html).